# Pass only date into sql : Unparseable date error

Tags: java, mysql, date

So in the JSP page I have

```
<br/> Date Published (mm/dd/yyyy): <input type="text" name="datePub"  value='<fmt:formatDate value="${b.datePub}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy"/>'/>
```

and in my class file

```
Date d= new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy").parse(request.getParameter("datePub"));
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(d.getTime());
...
insert.setDate(5, sqlDate);
```

and the error I got:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "12/12/2011"
```

My question is when I saw other post about unparseable date they include time as well but in sql I only want to insert the date. It should able to work with just the date without any locale or time. But why I cannot parse the date?

Comment: they are in different pattern.`"MM/dd/yyyy"` in jsp and `"MM-dd-yyyy"` in java,

Comment: shouldn't the SimpleDateFormat be ("MM/dd/yyyy")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use below pattern in java as you are using `pattern="MM/dd/yyyy"` in jsp. And your exception is also saying the same thing.

```
Date d= new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(request.getParameter("datePub"));
```